# Is there anyway to revert the multi-header group display changes that were introduced in ag-grid-community V20?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am about to update the ag-grid-community from v19+ to v20+.
 I noticed that the layout for multiple header group is changed, I am wondering is there a way to convert it back?
Here is the example using the latest version:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/mipCoMQvugdGnVA1 
Here is the example for v19:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/5kHGSYHw9Wtu7kJD 
The difference is that the newest version of ag-grid will not display the empty row under the Athlete Details.
So I am wondering is there any way to revert this layout change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was specifically changed here: [AG-2121 - only one paddedGroup for multiple columns](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/pull/3019).

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/

> AG-2121 - Feature Request - 20.2.0
>   Column Groups - Allow column-spanning across row header
>   groups when they belong to the same column group.

There does not appear to be a configuration switch to go back to the old behaviour.

It's hard to get back the vertical borders, but you can get back the horizontal border with CSS such as this:

```css
.ag-theme-balham .ag-header-cell, .ag-theme-balham .ag-header-group-cell {
    border-top-width: 1px !important;
}
```

One man's feature request is another man's bug.

It's probably intended, but I can't tell for sure, to be honest. If you think the new display is bugged in your case, you can try [making an issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues).

Comment: I see, thanks for providing the links, it was pretty useful!